# IndexError when trying to save an image with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to convert the PNG images that the user submits to JPEG, but when I try to save the image, I get

```
<type 'exceptions.IndexError'>: string index out of range
```

I am running the python script in Apache using CGI. When I run the script in console, it works ok.

This is the code.

```
if imghdr.what(filePath) == 'png':
    p = Image.open(filePath)
    p.save('../files/outfile.jpg', "JPEG")
    filePath = "../files/outfile.jpg"
```

The error occurs on the p.save() row. I thought that it was a permission problem, but I even gave 777 permissions on the files/ directory and it still won't work.

**EDIT**
This is what comes after the save() call.

```
 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in save(self=<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=512x512>, fp='../files/outfile.jpg', format='JPEG', **params={})
   1434 
   1435         # may mutate self!
=> 1436         self.load()
   1437 
   1438         self.encoderinfo = params
self = <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=512x512>, self.load = <bound method PngImageFile.load of <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=512x512>>
 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py in load(self=<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=512x512>)
    204                             break
    205                         else:
=>  206                             raise IndexError(ie)
    207 
    208                     if not s: # truncated jpeg
builtin IndexError = <type 'exceptions.IndexError'>, ie = IndexError('string index out of range',)
```

Comment: Please provide more stack-trace lines. And did you try using an absolute path?

Comment: Added the trace in the question.

Comment: I also tried using an absolute path. Nothing changes.

Comment: It's raising the error because the PNG is truncated. You could try editing PIL's ImageFile.py and set `LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES` to `True`. Alternatively why is the PNG truncated? Does the same happen with other PNGs? Can you open them in other image viewers? Does the same happen with Pillow instead of PIL?

Comment: I edited the wrong file the first time. Now I set the LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES to True and it works. Thanks. Please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm gonna answer this myself since Hugo didn't post an answer.

There is a flag called **LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES** that is set to **False** by default.

You have to go to **/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py** and set it to **True**.